# Existing libraries for web app sign-up, sign-in, manage passwords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, web-applications

Do the major web application frameworks (Rails, Django, etc) have libraries that provide functionality for signing in, signing up, creating usernames, changing passwords, and managing lost passwords?

It seems to me that this is common functionality that should be supported by some standard library, but I haven't seen anything in my searches.  I know about OpenID, but I am interested in non-OpenID solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has a standard User data model which is used extensively by Django applications.  There are also many apps available to ease user management, such as [django-registration](http://www.bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home).

Rails has many more options than Django, but has no standard User model.

Answer (score 5):

For Rails, the most popular one is [RestfulAuthentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master). It is so because it's been written by one of the core contributors to Rails.

Recently another one came out, that seems to be a bit cleaner and more feature-complete. I haven't taken the time to try it yet. Check out [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master).

Answer (score 3):

In Rails it is outside of core.  You need to either write your own or use a plugin such as Restful_Authentication - which has all the functionality you have mentioned.

If you want it all prebuilt in rails take a look at a skeleton app like Bort.

Answer (score 2):

As for Django, the User model has been already mentioned here. It is a part of the whole contrib app which handles authentication management (accounts, passwords, related routines). People usually add some user informations using some sort of user profile apps (there are some already built, check out [Django Pluggables](http://djangoplugables.com/)). For extended functionality, like user registration, (already mentioned here) [django-registration](http://www.bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) is most widely used.